# Python coding relating to function any and "more than once" keyword

Tags: python, algorithm, string-algorithm

I have this simple piece of code that tells me if a word in a given list appears in an article:

```
 if not any(word in article.text for word in keywords):
        print("Skipping article as there is no matching keyword\n")
```

What I need is if at least 3 words in the "keywords" list appear in the article - if they don't then it should skip the article.

Is there an easy way to do this? I can't seem to find anything.

Comment: `sum(word in article.text for word in keywords) >= 3` (write an explicit loop if you want to break earlier).

Comment: Thanks Sebastian - it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the set of keywords is large enough and the string being searched is long enough that it's often worth short-circuiting, a variation on other approaches that will stop when three hits are found (much like `any` stops when one hit found):

```
from itertools import islice

if sum(islice((1 for word in keywords if word in article.text), 3)) == 3:
```

Once you get three hits, it immediately stops iterating the keywords and the test passes.

Comment: My text and lists are pretty long so you provided a better solution - thanks!

Comment: @Del: if the text is large and there are many keywords then you could use Aho-Corasick algorithm (like `grep -Ff keywords.txt text.txt`).

Comment: I wouldn't have a clue how to do that Sebastian - any possibility of some python code as an example? I assume the grep is a linux bash command - or am I mistaken? My keywords are pulled from a db and the article is pulled down from a url

Comment: @Del: There are [a couple existing third party packages for performing Aho-Corasick efficiently in Python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=ahocorasick&submit=search); you'd want to check them for info. The basic idea is that you build a searcher from your keywords once, and you can then find all the words of your searcher in a single pass through the text (and you can process the text iteratively, so again, you can stop when you find three unique hits).

Answer (score 3):

You can count the number of items that satisfy a condition using this pattern:

```
sum(1 for x in xs if c(x))
```

Here you would do:

```
if sum(1 for word in keywords if word in article.text) >= 3:
    #
```

Comment: or `sum(word in article.txt for word in keywords)` (`True` and `False` are equivalent to `1` and `0`)

Comment: @kindall: you're right! I don't know why I've always done it using the explicit 1.

Answer (score 0):

> My text and lists are pretty long

if the text is large and there are many keywords then you could use [Aho-Corasick algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm) (like `grep -Ff keywords.txt text.txt`) e.g., if you want to find non-overlapping occurrences, you could [use `noaho` package](https://github.com/JDonner/NoAho) (not tested):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from itertools import islice
from noaho import NoAho  # $ pip install noaho

trie = NoAho()
for word in keywords:
    trie.add(word)
found_words = trie.findall_long(article.text)
if len(list(islice(found_words, 3))) == 3:
    print('at least 3 words in the "keywords" list appear in the article')
```