# Is there a shortcut when using multiple time "or" or maybe "and"?

Tags: python

```
string="abcd123"
if "a" or "b" or "c" in string:
    print("Yes")
```

is ther a shortcut for not typing "or" multiple times?

Comment: Your condition is always true, so it is pointless to write and `if`, so you could just do `print("Yes")` and it would be exactly equivalent to your code

Comment: What you probably *meant* to write is `if "a" in string or "b" in string or "c" in string: ...`

Answer (score 2):

The shortcut (for the correctly written code `if "a" in string or "b" in string or "c" in string:`) is the `any` function and a generator expression:

```
if any(s in string for s in ("a", "b", "c")):
```

That will return `True` as soon is it finds a value that is contained in `string`, or `False` if none are found; to search for more values, just add them to the inlined `tuple`. If you need to know *which* value, you can use `next` and a filtered genexpr to achieve a similar end result:

```
found_item = next((s for s in ("a", "b", "c") if s in string), None)  # Returns first item found or None
if found_item is not None:
    # Process found_item; it will be "a", "b" or "c", whichever was found first
```

Comment: Note: If the set of things to search for ("needles") is *huge*, and you need to know all of the ones found in the haystack, you might want to look at [my old answer on optimizing this scenario with Aho-Corasick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34820772/364696). Not worth it for just three strings to check normally (*maybe* if `string` was multiple GBs in size...), but worth noting when performance counts and you're testing for a lot of substrings.